# Where to get ruby-asana documentation

Tags: asana

I am new to Ruby and trying to learn how to use the Asana API. I have installed ruby-asana and am using Notepad++. I am having issues figuring out how to do things. I read that ruby-asana is a wrapper for Asana API and I see a few code snippets. Is there a help file somewhere that documents the classes, methods, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You can find these docs here: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/Asana/ruby-asana/master Note the menu on the left, which expands to provide reference docs on classes/methods.